# Calculation with tensors - showing an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a finite $n$-dimensional complex vector space with a skew symmetric bilinear form $p:V\otimes V\to\mathbb{C}$. Further, consider bases $\{v_i\}$ and $\{u_i\}$ of $V$ such that $$p(v_i\otimes u_j)=\delta_{ij}=-p(u_j\otimes v_i)$$ and an automorphism $f\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$.

If we have for all $j=1,...,n$ the equality $$\sum_{i=1}^np(f(v_j)\otimes f(u_i))\otimes f(v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^np(v_j\otimes u_i)\otimes f(v_i),$$

is it possible to deduce $p(f(v_j)\otimes f(u_i))=p(v_j\otimes u_i)$ for all $i,j=1,...,n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the fact that the bases are dual, and $f^{-1}$, we can deduce from the first equation that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \otimes p(f(u_i) \otimes f(v_j)) = v_j$$
which by the fact that the $v_i$ are a basis give that
$$ p(f(u_i) \otimes f(v_j)) = \delta_{ij} = p(u_i \otimes v_j)$$
which is what you wanted. This means that $f \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ preserves the skew-symmetric form, and belongs to the symplectic group defined by $p$.

Comment: You could consider the first equation to take values in $\mathbb{C} \otimes V$, so apply the linear transformation $\mathrm{id}_\mathbb{C} \otimes f^{-1}$ to both sides.

Comment: The first equation I wrote is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i b_i = v_j$ for some scalars $b_i$. Since the $v_i$ are a basis, we must have $b_j = 1$, and $b_i = 0$ for $i \neq j$.